# Please help me solve this differential equation

Tags: derivatives

Hi I'm having a slight issue trying to solve this differential equation. I would greatly appreciate any help or tips to solve this problem.

[image]

[click here for the equation please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnhak.png)

Comment: AAli could you please type out your question rather than insert an image, thanks. Also, could you let us know what you've tried thus far?

Comment: Please use MathJax (i.e. LaTeX commands) to format mathematical notations, see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Use $y=u^2$ and $dy=2udu$ to simplify the equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can by sure separate it...:

$$\frac{1+\sqrt y-\frac1y}{\sqrt y-y-y\sqrt y}dy=dx\implies-\int\frac{y^{3/2}+y-1}{y^{5/2}+y^2-y^{3/2}}dy=\int dx=x+C$$

substitute in the left integral $\;t=y^{1/2}\implies dt=\frac{dy}{2\sqrt y}\implies dy=2tdt\implies\;$

$$-\int\frac{y^{3/2}+y-1}{y^{5/2}+y^2-y^{3/2}}dy=-\int\frac{t^3+t^2-1}{t^5+t^4-t^3}2t\,dt=-2\int\frac{t^4+t^3-t}{t^3(t^2+t-1)}=$$

$$=-2\int\frac{t^4+t^3-t}{t^3\left(t+\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)\left(t+\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)}dt$$

Now, the integral is ugly as one can expect it to be...but it is solvable by simple fractions.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

General method.
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = G(y)
\\
\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{G(y)}
\\
x = \int \frac{1}{G(y)}\;dy + C
$$
and solve the result for $y$ in terms of $x$.

Answer (score -1):

this equation is separable
$$\frac{y'(x)}{\frac{1-\sqrt{y(x)}-y(x)}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y(x)}}-y(x)^{3/2}}}=1$$
and then
$$y'(x)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y(x)}}-y(x)^{3/2}}-\frac{\sqrt{y(x)}}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y(x)}}-y(x)^{3/2}}-\frac{y(x)}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y(x)}}-y(x)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: why the $-1$? i reelly don't understand

Comment: The second line is identical to the original equation, I cannot see how that helps towards a solution via separation of variables. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: this line is the hint how we can integrate the term, you gave me the $-1$?

Comment: yes you are overlooking the main step

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I've no idea who downvoted (some people around here has a very quick finger on the  mouse...), but for remarking that the equation is separable your answer doesn't seem to make things much simpler for the asker...

Comment: we can not make all things simplier

Comment: are looking your steps much simplier? i mean not